# Replace tweet urls with string

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I am trying to delete all URLS in a big csv-file and replace it with the string "URL" (a so-called equivalence token). The code does what I want, but it clumps/concatenates some rows together in one row.

That means that the original csv has 63.000 rows and the output csv only 55000. That is not what I want. How can I replace links with this token and leave all columns separated?

```
#links are replaced with links

import re
with open('data_feat1.csv',"r", encoding="utf-8") as oldfile2, open('data_feat2.csv', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as newfile2:
    for line in oldfile2:
        line=re.sub(r"http\S+", r"URL", line) #replaces links with "URL"
        newfile2.write(line)
newfile2.close()
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a ' to "URL":

```
line=re.sub(r"http\S+", r'URL"', line) #replaces links with "URL"
```

I do not know why it worked, but it did!

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it works is because it is using a regular expression to search for `http`.

the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)handles regular expressions. `re.sub` will replace the matched regular expression with the second argument (`URL"` in your case).

what that regular expression is doing is searching for `http` and everything after it. "everything after it" is designated by the `\S+` characters which is saying "everything that goes until white space"

Take a look at [`Pythex`](http://pythex.org/). It'll be a good place to learn how regular expression work in Python